# reformatting my ssd from ps4 to PC (windows 11)

Tags: ssd, formatting, usb-storage, format, samsung-ssd

I have a portable SSD I would like to use to store games on. I have used this ssd on my PS4 and now want to use it on my PC but i can't seem to open it on my PC the only thing i can do with it is remove it but it doesn't show up in my files. Does someone know what i have to do to fix this? (I think I need to reformat it but I have no idea how to do this)

The ssd is a samsing T5 portable ssd and is not empty but i don't have a problem with deleting the files stored on it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you see the drive in File Explorer?   Right Click and find the Format command and format it

Comment: @John no i don't, normally a new drive shows up next to my internal drives but this one does nothing.

Comment: Does it appear in disk management then?

Comment: The drive may have developed a hardware problem (older drive)

Comment: it does appear in the diskmanager but there is unasigned written next to it

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by running diskpart and cleaning the SSD, this formats it back to factory settings. Than I used deskmanager to get the right format for the disk.

THIS WILL DELETE ALL STORED FILES!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).